# Class cast exception when describing a data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a small dataset in csv format with two columns of integers over which I am computing summary statistics. There should be no missing or bad data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val raw = sc.textFile("skill_aggregate.csv")

val struct = StructType(StructField("personid", IntegerType, false) 
  :: StructField("numSkills", IntegerType, false) :: Nil)

val rows = raw.map(_.split(",")).map(x => Row(x(0), x(1)))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, struct)

df.describe().show()
```

The last line gives me:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

which of course implies some bad data. The weird bit is that I can "collect" the entire data set without issue which implies each row correctly conforms to the `IntegerType` described in the schema. Also odd is that I can't find any NA values when I open the dataset up in R.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the databricks-csv reader (https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) ? is easier and safer to create dataframes from a csv file and it allows you to define a schema of your fields (and avoid cast problems).

The code is very simple to achieve it :

```
myDataFrame = sqlContext.load(source="com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true", path = myFilePath)
```

Greetings,

JG

Comment: I'll give this a shot thanks. Still curious as to why I am getting the error though.

Comment: This is a nice package but it loads everything in as Strings, without (as far as I can tell) an option to convert to Ints and thus "describe" has no effect.

Comment: You can create the schema as you defined previously, and then pass it to the databricks-csv loader : myDataFrame = sqlContext.load(source="com.databricks.spark.csv", schema=struct, header="true", path = fileSource) , and it should work

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. It was necessary to add `toInt` to each row entry:

```
val rows = raw.map(_.split(",")).map(x => Row(x(0).toInt, x(1).toInt))
```